# How can I get a window handle of the CWnd object in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, mfc, handle, cwnd

I have Epic Editor which returns a handle to the window (see Java code from plugin_1 below):

```
int handle = com.arbortext.epic.Application.getActiveWindow().getNativeHandle();
```

In fact, this handle is `CWnd *` pointer. Its direct transfer to the native plugin_2 does not work. Instead, we have to use dll with MFC support with the call

```
HWND __stdcall GetHandle(CWnd *cp)
{
 HWND hWnd = cp->GetSafeHwnd();
 return hWnd; 
}
```

How can I rewrite this code in Delphi without MFC? I mean the extraction of window handle from the pointer to the `CWnd` object.

Comment: Exporting MFC class types from a DLL intended for use from any language other than VC++ was awfully short-sighted of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write this in Delphi in a safe way. That's because `CWnd` is a C++ class and you can't import C++ classes into Delphi code. I suppose you could reverse engineer the memory layout of `CWnd` but I'd be very sceptical about the wisdom of talking that approach. My recommendation would be to stick with the MFC DLL.